# Offload dri to a render node in xorg

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, xorg

There is new feature in mesa `DRI_PRIME` emerged to keep up with modern hybrid graphics on laptops. I'd like to use it for desktop too. Powersaving is always good.

So I make xorg to use only intel driver disabling `AutoAddGPU` option. Then, when I need to run gpu consuming application I may wake up my radeon cards. DRI render nodes emerges after modprobing radeon module:

```
# ls /dev/dri/
card0  card1  card2
controlD64  controlD65  controlD66
renderD128  renderD129  renderD130
```

How can I make xorg use this nodes for offloading rendering?

I tried `xrandr --listproviders` but got only single provider corresponded to embedded intel card. May render nodes be used as providers?